# Sikuli Check multiple of the same images on screen

Tags: sikuli

I can check if the image exist with exists()

But i want to know if i can check if the same image appears more than once appearing on the screen, for example:

if a ball exists once click a button...

if a ball exists twice on screen click another button... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [findAll method](http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.findAll) from Sikuli Region class. The example code will look like this:

```
def returnImageCount(image):
    count = 0
    for i in findAll(image):
        count += 1
    return count

imageCount = returnImageCount(image)

if imageCount == 1:
    click(buttonX.image)
elif imageCount == 2:
    click(buttonY.image)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Python's list comprehension to do it:

```
imageCount = len(list([x for x in findAll(image)]))

#the rest is like @Eugene's answer
if imageCount == 1:
    click(buttonA)
elif imageCount == 2:
    click(buttonB)
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

To check all the occurrences of an Image on the screen use the below, additional click is added to get the confirmation of the image exact location.

#### code:

```
Screen s = new Screen();
Iterator<Match> it = s.findAll(Imagepath);

while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("the match is "+it.next().click());
}
```

Or you can find the length of the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Use findall method of Region object. It gives you a list of all matching image/pattern. Sikuli documentation has good details on usage. Refer here http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html#Region.findAll

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to count the number of a certain image on the window you could use:

```
Image1 = ("Image1.png")
ImagesFound = list(findAll(Image1))
numberFound = len(ImagesFound)
print(numberFound)
```

And if you would like to count the number of a certain image on the most front window, like a pop-up. 
You could use:

```
Image1 = ("Image1.png")
appWindow = App.focusedWindow()
ImagesFound = list(appWindow.findAll(Image1))
numberFound = len(ImagesFound)
print(numberFound)
```